# Как по клику передать id картинки в поле формы?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите как по клику на картинку, ее адрес прописать в поле формы например: `#img_avatar` и какие способы существуют для решения данной задачи? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так:

```
var $img   = $('#img_avatar'), // <img src="..." id="img_avatar">
    $input = $('#some_input'); // <input ... id="some_input">

$img.on('click', function(){
    $input.val($(this).attr('src'));
});
```